# Add javascript namespacing to a huge project

Tags: javascript

I have a huge project, around 4000 lines JavaScript.
This project was never intended to be used in another projectsite, it was allways planned as singlesideapplication.
Sadly the customer changed his opinion and now it should run with 3 other projects inculded in the same singlesiteapp.

Now I have to be sure not a single variable or method can be deleted or touched "per accident" from another loaded js code, e.g. "var mPath = /MyPath" could of course be overwritten if the next project load like "var mPath = /NowNewPath/".

How to add get sure that doesnt happen?
Add namespacing right?
Any ideas how to solve this clean for all 4000 lines of code?

Comment: You've answered yourself, use namespacing... yes.

Comment: Refactoring 4000 lines of code is a very huge task. Though not impossible. And potentially what you gain worths this effort. I suggest you [this article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) by Addy Osmani abount Javascript namespacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, wrap everything in an [Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to enclose all variables in an isolated scope.

```
(function() {
    /* all 4000 lines of code */
})();
```

Second, ensure no accidental global variables - declare local variables with `var` keyword.

```
(function() {
    /* if you see this within the 4000 lines of code */
    somePath = "abc";
    /* change to this */
    var somePath = "abc";
})();
```

Lastly, expose only one (or as few as possible) global variable as the entry point to your library.

```
/* "myLib" should be your globally-unique namespace */
myLib = (function() {
    /* the 4000 lines of code */

    return {
        /* attach functions and variables */
        somePath: somePath;
    };
})();

alert(somePath); // undefined
alert(myLib.somePath); // "abc"
```

Comment: I would not like the reference to `window`. Why not return something in the function and store it in a variable `myLib`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to namespace if you use the immediately-invoked function expression for every JS file, or for logical blocks in your JS files. So you'll get:

```
// a.js
(function () {
  var mPath = "/MyPath";
})();

// b.js
(function () {
  var mPath = "/NowNewPath";
})();
```

Both have their own scope and can't access the variables of the other scope. If one module needs to call code of the other you'd export a defined interface for each module. I.e.

```
// a.js with a global variable
(function () {
  var exports = {};
  var mPath = "/MyPath";
  exports.getPath = function () {
    return mPath;
  }
  window.moduleA = exports;
})();

// b.js
(function () {
  var mPath = moduleA.getPath() || "/NowNewPath";
})();
```

or return the export:

```
var moduleA = (function () {
  var exports = {};
  // ....
  return exports;
})();
```

or use something like require.js. All methods should be quick to add, but you need to find the module dependencies, which you would anyway with the namespacing approach.